# UI design for Rating Scale with 0.5 incremental point scale

Tags: ratings, style-guide, scale

I'm working on a rating scale that will consider point decimal with 0.5 increments from 1 to 5. The use for this is to rate/score. The previous rating scale just considers whole numbers from 1 to 5 with this format

[image: rating scale]

However, when you add 0.5 increments, the easiest solution is to add 10 circles each having these numbers

1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5

**Some solutions I thought**

1. Use Scale Slider

[image: scale slide]

Con: It doesn't fit very well because the use of the rating scale is for rating or scoring. Thus, scale slider does not easily be understandable on the use for rating.

2. Dropdown

[image: dropdown select]

3. Button Group Style / Pagination-like Style

[image: button group]

I'm still looking for better ways to present it. If you encounter something similar, I would appreciate your thoughts on how to make it better.

Comment: Change the scale from 1-5 to 1-10?

Comment: If only we can just allow whole numbers, we will stick to whole numbers. But, it's necessary to allow 0.5 increments because of the kind of rating we do on the app.

Answer (score 7):

You could always use the standard 5 button full number intervals like you were previously but allow the selection of half intervals. Like so:

[image]

Example seen here (I have no affiliation): https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

This format will allow you to take up the same amount of space and not overclutter the component while still allowing half-step selection. You could of course use your number scale instead of stars if you prefer.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I would have recommended as well.

Comment: We use five stars to rate our application forms and get ridiculously high response rates, so I'm a fan. Everyone understands stars.

Comment: Thanks @DasBeasto for this. The half-star format is a good solution. However, my concern is that this will be used to rate a person. I'm thinking a star might might make it look inappropriately to rate a person? If it is to rate movies, books or non-living things; it might be ok, but for a person, would that still be fine? Would be happy to get your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Numeric rating scales – even more so with half-values – are usually misleading in that they suggest a higher scale level than appropriate. Is it really a categoric scale, an ordinal scale, a linear ratio scale or even an absolute scale? Probed subjects will often assume a different one than the questionnaire designer, and analysts will be tempted to use improper statistical measures, e.g. geometric average for a categoric scale, if the data is numeric.

I do not know the exact scenario, but it is quite likely that a symbolic scale, e.g. using emoticons or just `+` and `–`, would be more appropriate.